# I can't figure out how to make a command run only ONCE every night at midnight in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Just like the title says, this is my code but I can't figure out why the code isn't working. What happens is no matter what time it is, the document.getElementById will keep running every time I refresh the page. Any tips?

Edit: To clarify, I didn't break cases 0-5 because the case 6 code I want to run every day at midnight... I'm just stuck because no matter what time it is, every time I refresh the page it chooses a new value in the array.

```js
var raad = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giraffe', 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion',
  'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koala'
]
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 2:
  case 3:
  case 4:
  case 5:
  case 6:
    document.getElementById("wikiframe").src = raad[Math.floor(Math.random() * raad.length)];
    break;
}
```

Comment: So only who enters your site exactly at midnight will see the image? This don't make senSe

Comment: Oh I'm sorry if it sounded confusing :/ What I mean is I have it programmed to switch links in an <iframe> for html5, however I thought my code would execute it once every midnight but instead if you keep refreshing the page, it will keep refreshing the array, sending the user to a new link every time rather than once a day.

Answer (score 0):

switch statements will fire all cases until a `break` or `return`

```
ch (new Date().getDay()) {
      case 0:
        break; // need to break or the switch will keep going through cases til the end
      .
      .
      .
      case 6:
        document.getElementById("wikiframe").src = raad[Math.floor(Math.random() * raad.length)];
        break;
    }
```

Comment: So if i add a break at the end of each case but only have case 6 run the code, it will run once a day?

Comment: Oh just to clarify, the reason why I didn't break each case was because I want the case 6 code to run every day at midnight... but only once

Comment: Uhm, this switch statement with run case 6 on Saturdays I think? The getDay call returns a number that represents the day of the week.

Comment: I think that switch statements are also for days of the week, like 0 is sunday, 1 is monday, etc. I know that doing getDay also does the same thing, but in this case it does the same thing where it would keep calling the function every time I refresh it. I'm trying to code a website so that every day at midnight it takes a url from my array and sets it as an iframe in html so that every day ONCE a day it can show a random url.

Comment: @CIA11

https://repl.it/@joel_perkins/checkMidnightHour

This function checks if it is currently in the midnight hour and returns true if it is.